# Entity Framework 5 and SQL Server CE: execute generated db schema

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Project is using:

- ASP.NET MVC4
- Entity Framework 5
- SQL Server CE
- IDE: Visual Studio Express 2012

**Issue:**

Entity Framework (model-first) has you add your models in the `.edmx` then you right-click the `.edmx` to generate database schema. However in VS Express we're unable to right-click the `.sqlce` file contents to load the option to "Execute Ctrl+Shift+E" the way we can in Visual Studio.

**Question:**

How can I run the script that was generated by the Entity Framework?

*Previous attempts:*

So far I've tried to open the Compact database in SQL Server Management Studio but I return an error that SSMS can't load the compact db because it's not the correct type also from Database Explorer I've pasted the script into a NewQuery window and ran the script but threw errors as well.

Comment: You may need to "fix" the script, as I describe here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/02/fixing-entity-framework-designer.html - and the run it with the SQL Server Compact Toolbox (standalone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded *[SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/)* and was able to run the script. Thanks and credit to ErikEJ.